# Excepción al sumar matrices (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: java

Tengo un conflicto con la suma de matrices, ya que al colocar la fila de mi matriz mayor que la columna mi programa devuelve un error:

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4 at clases.ClasePrincipal.main(ClasePrincipal.java:16)**

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

A continuacion dejo mi código completo con comentarios y gracias a los que respondan:

```java
package clases;

public class ClasePrincipal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * int matrizUno[][] = new int[5][4];
         * int matrizDos[][] = new int[5][4];
         * int resultante[][] = new int[5][4];
         */

        /*
         * int matrizUno[][] = new int[4][4];
         * int matrizDos[][] = new int[4][4];
         * int resultante[][] = new int[4][4];
         */

        int matrizUno[][] = new int[3][4];
        int matrizDos[][] = new int[3][4];
        int resultante[][] = new int[3][4];

        // LLenado de la Matriz Uno.
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizUno.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= matrizUno.length; j++) {
                matrizUno[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            }
        }

        // LLenado de la Matriz Dos.
        for (int h = 0; h < matrizDos.length; h++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= matrizDos.length; k++) {
                matrizDos[h][k] = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            }
        }

        //Suma
        for (int i = 0; i < resultante.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= resultante.length; j++) {
                resultante[i][j] = matrizUno[i][j] + matrizDos[i][j];
            }
        }

        //Imprimir Matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < matrizUno.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= matrizUno.length; j++) {
                System.out.print("[ " + matrizUno[i][j] + " ]");
            }

            if (i == 1) {

                System.out.print("   +   ");

            } else {

                System.out.print("       ");
            }

            for (int l = 0; l <= matrizDos.length; l++) {
                System.out.print("[ " + matrizDos[i][l] + " ]");
            }

            if (i == 1) {

                System.out.print("   =   ");

            } else {

                System.out.print("       ");
            }

            for (int m = 0; m <= resultante.length; m++) {
                System.out.print("[ " + resultante[i][m] + " ]");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fijate lo que estás haciendo con los `for` y el método `length`. ¿Tiene sentido que tanto `i` como `j` recorran igualmente desde `0` hasta `M.length`, siendo M cualquier matriz? igual si jugas con el menor o menor o igual, fijate la documentación de Java para `length`. Deberías usar algo como `M[0].length`. También te aconsejo usar otro título, porque "Suma de dos matrices" no describe tu pregunta. Lee [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para saber más.

Comment: D4RIO gracias por responder me has aclarado bastante el panorama de mi dificultad gracias si lo resuelvo te cuento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comentarios

Siempre es bueno analizar matemáticamente que la operación sea válida, para ello tomaremos los casos que sean inválidos.

**Condiciones de invalidez:**

1. Las matrices difieren de número de filas
2. Las matrices tienen 0 filas
3. Al menos una matriz tiene 0 columnas
4. El número de columnas difieren (sea en la propia matriz o en la otra matriz)

**Impresión de una matriz**

Para para imprimir te será muy útil la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), esto evitará que llames muchas veces a `System.out.print`, en vez de ello, construyes un String y lo imprimes una vez que esté listo.

Otra que te será muy útil será la clase [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html), en especial el método [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double%5B%5D)) o si no te gusta el formato [Arrays.deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

## En código

- Haremos un método que sume las matrices y otro método que le de formato para imprimirlas.
- Cada condición de invalidez la arrojaremos como un [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) (un argumento que no cumple con las características requeridas), si no has visto las excepciones, este [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) te será muy útil
- Como tienes bien el llenado de las matrices lo omitiremos

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main (String []args) {
        double[][] matrixA = {{22, 50}, {17, 18}, {42, 32}};
        double[][] matrixB = {{15, 14}, {48, 31}, {22, 50}};

        try {
            double[][] matrixR = sumMatrix(matrixA, matrixB);
            System.out.println(formatMatrixSum(matrixA, matrixB, matrixR));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Illegal matrix operation");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Given 2 matrix of the same size n x m returns the matrix sum
     * @param A Matrix A
     * @param B Matrix B
     * @return the matrix sum A + B
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if n < 1 || m < 1 || column sizes < 1
     */
    public static double[][] sumMatrix(double[][] A, double[][] B) {
        if (A.length < 1 || B.length < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One or more Matrix is not initialized");
        if (A.length != B.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix sizes doesn't match");

        int size = A[0].length;
        if (size < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix columns not initialized");

        double[][] R = new double[A.length][size];

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i].length != size || B[i].length != size)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix column sizes doesn't match");
            for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++)
                R[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }

        return R;
    }

    /**
     * @param A Matrix A
     * @param B Matrix B
     * @param R Matrix R = A + B
     * @return A pretty String for user visualization of A + B
     */
    public static String formatMatrixSum(
            double[][] A,
            double[][] B,
            double[][] R
    ){
        if (A.length < 1 || B.length < 1 || R.length < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One or more Matrix is not initialized");
        if (A.length != B.length || R.length != B.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One or more Matrix is not initialized");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        int size = A[0].length;
        if (size < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix columns not initialized");

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i].length != size || B[i].length != size || R[i].length != size)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix column sizes doesn't match");

            stringBuilder
                    .append(Arrays.toString(A[i]))
                    .append('\t');
            if (i == A.length / 2)
                stringBuilder.append('+');

            stringBuilder
                    .append(Arrays.toString(B[i]))
                    .append('\t');

            if (i == A.length / 2)
                stringBuilder.append('=');

            stringBuilder
                    .append(Arrays.toString(R[i]))
                    .append('\n');

        }

        return stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1).toString();

    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Salida]